# Are there any ways to generate a bpmn schema or picture with schema from Apache Camel routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel, bpmn, business-process-management

Are there any ways to generate a bpmn schema or picture with schema from Apache Camel routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check hawtio camel plugin for some ideas. There are also camel tooling in latest jBoss fuse that potentially can be used (https://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html).